# How do I use Svgeezy? (SVG fallback)

Tags: svg, png, fallback

I'm trying to switch out the SVG images I am using to PNG on browsers that don't support them - namely IE8/7 and old versions of Android.

After a lot of looking, I think I've found the tool for the job - [svgeezy](https://github.com/benhowdle89/svgeezy) - The issue is, I have no idea how to use it! (I don't understand the tiny documentation given)

I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain it to like I'm two, I ahve no idea where to begin (I'm new at this) :)

p.s - I know there are other ways of doing it, but I was having all kinds of trouble with using the SVGs as a background, I want to avoid that way of doing it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Svgeezy's API is not all that intuitive or powerful, but it's simple. The first parameter is the class name you want to avoid replacing (if any) and the second is the type of fallback. This works at the document level, so you can't replace some SVGs with JPG and others with PNG.

```
// will replace all SVGs with PNGs
svgeezy.init('nothing', 'png');

// will replace all SVGs with JPGs except those that have class="noreplace"
svgeezy.init('noreplace', 'jpg');
```

Your fallback should have the same file name as the original SVG. So, for example, if you want to replace `logo.svg`, then `logo.png` should be in the same directory.

To load the javascript put this just before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    svgeezy.init('whatever', 'png');
</script>
```

Comment: Okay, that's making a bit more sense for me now, organized all my files :) thank you - one last thing, how do I make it actually 'fire' if that makes sense. What exactly do I need to type to get it working? Putting it inside script tags isn't working - I doubt it would ever be that simple! (I little knowledge of JavaScript)

Comment: @Ollie I have included an example on how to make it fire at the correct moment.

Comment: I know it's a massive ask, but can you have a look at this https://www.dropbox.com/s/kn4cfuhulky33oi/SVGEEZY.zip and see if I'm doing it right. I can't believe I'm still struggling with this. http://jsfiddle.net/xWaVr/2/ (obviously it won't work with jsFiddle) - Just say wether the placement is correct.

Comment: Woops, it looks like svgeezy has a bug: if you don't avoid any elements it won't do anything, so you must do something like `svgeezy.init("nothing", 'png');` where `nothing` is a class you don't actually use. It seems that in your attempts to make it work you did both methods of initializing svgeezy, I've updated the code with the simplest method.

Comment: hi guys, just thought I'd chip in and say that I've updated the plugin so you can pass in `false` as the first parameter if you have no "avoiding classes"!